# Binning data dynamically

Tags: sas

I have desire to create variable for binning data in SAS. However, this seems to be harder than one would assume.

For Example I would have:

```
var1 
1
2
3 
5
11
17
...
```

I want to have bins size of 3:

```
var1 bin_var
1    1
2    1
3    1
5    2
11   4
17   6
...
```

I've come up with a way to do this by looping over the whole range:

```
%do i=&bin_min %to &bin_max %by &bin_size;
data foobar;
    set foobar;
        if (&i =< var_to_bin < (&i+&bin_size))  then; bin_var=&i;
run;
%end;
```

However, this is very slow, not to mention just plain silly. Anyone know better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you don't have to loop outside the Data Step, you can do that inside the Data Step and get the same result.

```
data foobar;
    set foobar;
    %do i=&bin_min %to &bin_max %by &bin_size;
        if (&i =< var_to_bin < (&i+&bin_size))  then; bin_var=&i;
    %end;
run;
```

Or you can just use a couple functions and forgo the loop all together.

```
data have;
input var1;
datalines;
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
15
17
28
21
;

%let bin_size=3;
%let bin_min=1;
%let bin_max=6;

data want;
set have;
bin = max(&bin_min,min(&bin_max,floor( (var1-1) /&bin_size)+1));
run;
```

Comment: This is almost perfect. If I set bin_min=2, then first few go to wrong bin. But this could be handled by if step before bin-line.

Comment: how do you want to handle values that fall outside of your min and max bin number?

Comment: Depends on the case, but I think something along the lines of : %if var1<min_nbin or var1>max bin then bin_var=.

Answer (score 1):

How about using simple division?  You can add additional code to deal with bin_min/bin_max issues if you need to.

```
data want;
  set have;
  bin_var= ceil(var1/&bin_size.);
run;
```

Comment: This is more or less the same as Dom's second solution, but somewhat more straightforward to use `ceil` instead of `floor` I think.

Comment: You still need the min(max()) as he wants to set bounds on the bin numbers.

Comment: I tend to think in C-style integer division in these problems where floor(a/b) is the SAS analog.  My brain just defaults to it...

Comment: Haven't tested, but this should not work if I want to set beginning value to X and want to bin x+y. But for some cases, sure.

Comment: You're welcome to add some additional detail to the OP.  For the case presented, this works; anything else would require some additional code (like Dom presents) but should be easily modifiable.